# Does a proper closed convex function have a nonempty subdifferential? If so where can I find the result?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

I want to know if given $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ proper closed and convex, $X$ being a vector space (say: euclidean, for simplicity)
then does exist $x \in domf$ (i,e the set where f admits finite values) such that
$\partial f(x) \neq \emptyset$?

If so, where can I find a reference with such result?

Comment: What does it mean that $f$ is closed?

Comment: It means its epigraph is closed. In this case it's equivalent to say it's lower semi-continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}-\sqrt{1-x^2} & x\in[-1,1]\\\infty & x\not\in[-1,1]\end{cases}$. The subdifferential at $x=1$ is empty but the function is in $\Gamma_0(\mathbb{R})$, the set of closed, proper, convex functions.